# Typescript: CSS modules will break compilation in Mocha

Tags: typescript, mocha.js, css-modules, react-css-modules, ts-node

I have a component using [react-css-modules](https://github.com/gajus/react-css-modules) and I run my tests with [mocha](https://mochajs.org/) and [ts-node](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node), which results in my test breaking because it can't find the module `foo.css`. How could I accomplish this?

The specific command I run for my test is: `./node_modules/.bin/mocha --compilers ts:ts-node/register,tsx:ts-node/register -r tsconfig-paths/register test/unit/**/*.test.*`

I think my ideal solution would simply be to ignore `.css` imports and return a mock object, this way the `styleName` prop in my components would stay the same and asserting would be easy, but I'm open to any solution that will let me run my tests.

Answer (score 3):

If the error says "SyntaxError: Unexpected token" in the css file, then you need to require or import `ignore-styles`. In my case, I was getting `error TS2307: Cannot find module './style.css'.` So the solution was to define `TS_NODE_FILES=true`, so the full command is

```
TS_NODE_FILES=true TS_NODE_COMPILER_OPTIONS='{"module": "commonjs"}' mocha -r ts-node/register,test/setup.ts **/*.test.ts **/*.test.tsx
# I do `import 'ignore-styles'` in test/setup.ts
```

I'm not entirely sure, but I think this is caused by the `definitions.d.ts` file, which defines css files, being ignored. TS_NODE_FILES ensures that all definitions are being read.

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore the stylesheets by installing [ignore-styles](https://github.com/bkonkle/ignore-styles#installation) to your dev dependencies, and then adding

```
--require ignore-styles
```

to either your `mocha.opts` or your command line arguments.